# mechanize select instagram form

Tags: python, instagram, mechanize

I'm looking to automatically log into Instagram [login](http://www.instagram.com/accounts/login) using Python Mechanize, but I just get an error `"No form matching nr=0"`, here's my code.

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
response = br.open("http://www.instagram.com/accounts/login)
br.select_form(nr = 0)
br.form["username"] = "[my username]"
br.form["password"] = "[my password]"
br.method = "POST"
response = br.submit()
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this? The form has no name, so I can't manually enter a name.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[1]/input')
username.send_keys('my_username')

password = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/input')
password.send_keys('my_password')
password.submit()

input('logged in...?')  # temporary so browser doesn't close immediately

driver.close()
```